# Button's height automatically changes android

Tags: android, button, layout, height

I have an activity with a LinearLayout with buttons arranged horizontally, a LinearLayout with TextViews horizontally oriented, a gridview and a TextView.
The 1st LinearLayout has 3 buttons, one of which is initially has its visibility set to "GONE". The LinearLayout must have a weight of 2/28, which it has at first, but when the 3rd button appears, it reshapes entirely. I also mention that when I test this on a larger screen, the proportions remain the same and it all works perfectly. The drawable used is a simple shape with rounded corners and stroke.

```
    <!-- this button is initially set as GONE and then it changes his height -->
            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/previous"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:text="@string/previous"
                android:textColor="#606060"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:hint="Previous"/>

<!-- This button is visible from the very beginning, with the correct height -->
            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/next"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:text="@string/next"
                android:textColor="#606060"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:hint="Next"/>
            </LinearLayout>
```

I mention I set the visibility programatically, it it's of any relevance:

```
_previous.setVisibility(GONE);
```

and respectively

```
_previous.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
```

Any idea why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Here are two photos to better depict my idea:
[Img1](http://oi44.tinypic.com/2r78os0.jpg)
[Img2](http://oi41.tinypic.com/2hh3vvt.jpg)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue by getting the LayoutParams and setting the height to be 2/28 of the screen, as it should have been from the very first time and now it works like charms.
Below is the source code:

```
DisplayMetrics _metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int _height = _metrics.heightPixels; //height of the screen

LayoutParams _layoutParamsButton = (LayoutParams) _previous.getLayoutParams(); 
_layoutParamsButton.height = _height/28*2;
_previous.setLayoutParams(_layoutParamsButton);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you mean

`_previous.setVisibility(GONE);
and respectively
_previous.setVisibility(VISIBLE);`

I think you mean you hide the button with `View.GONE` and show it with `View.VISIBLE`.

Do you understand the difference between `View.GONE` and `View.INVISIBLE`?

`View.GONE` causes the layout to measure itself as if the button never existed.  `View.INVISIBLE` causes the layout to measure itself including the button but not show it on screen.  If you set it to `View.GONE` initially, then set it to `View.VISIBLE`, the entire layout will be re-measured and redrawn.

Without understanding your question, my guess is that you should be using `View.INVISIBLE` and `View.VISIBLE` in your code.

You should also use `android:visibility="invisible"` in your XML for the initial state.

Comment: Yes, I do know the difference between gone, invisible and visible. I need the button to be gone, because I need the textview to be centered when the button is not present on the screen, which I cannot do if the button is set to invisible. To be more explicit, I want the button to lead me to the previous month only if it is not showing the current month.
My question was why isn't the button just like the other ones, although I use the same specifications for it (it also alters a bit the height of the other ones).